# KnockoutJs: Render members of an array three per row

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array with colors. I am foreaching the array and render divs with background color from it. The problem is I want to have only three colors per row. For example, If I have 10 colors, there should be four rows. First three with three colors and the last - with one.

html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: colors">
    <div data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: $data, 
                              width: '20px', 
                              height: '20px'}">                              
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var MyViewModel = function() {
  this.colors = ko.observableArray(['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple','white', 'black', 'orange']);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/142/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it with a CSS class and the overflow CSS attribut. For all web design  features, it's more usefull to use CSS.

```
.container div
{
    display:inline-block;
}

.container
{
    border : 1px solid;
    max-width: 70px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

For HTML :

```
<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: colors">
    <div data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: $data, 
                              width: '20px', 
                              height: '20px'}">                              
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can create a computed that groups the colors as follow :

```
this.groupedColors = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var groups = [];
        var colors = this.colors();
        for (var index = 0; index < colors.length; index++) {
            var group = [];
            for (var indexInGroup = 0; index < colors.length && indexInGroup < 3; index++, indexInGroup++) {
                group.push(colors[index]);
            }
            groups.push(group);
        }
        return groups;
    },
    owner: this
});
```

And use this view :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: groupedColors">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <div data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: $data}" class="colorBox"></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/145/)

Comment: Thanks! I will use Cedric solution as it is more simple and it does what I need. But I also like Your solution very much.

Comment: You beat me to it...here's my virtually identical fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/148/ :)